# Where to find the build number INSIDE an install DVD of Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dvd, build-version

It's not written on the DVD itself and I don't have the DVD sleeve anymore.

Comment: For which OS X version? Snow Leopard (10.6)? or Lion (10.7)?

Comment: This *should* be printed on the physical DVD :-[.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly through the DVD as you asked, but Apple provides a [list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1633) will all the build numbers for the Retail installation disks.

[image]

Once you've run the Installer, you could always go to the **Apple Menu ()** and choose **About this Installer**, which should provide the build number.

Answer (score 7):

Check the **SystemVersion.plist** file that is on the Install Media.

Within the install media is the file containing the Build number, it is located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`

The string value for the Key **ProductBuildVersion** is the information you are looking for.

**Note:** *This tip is useful for getting the Build versions on any OS X bootable disk, regardless of install ability.*